# Clean "settings" binding in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I was recently working with a lot of bindings to my configuration settings in XAML. Storing column widths/control sizes/window positions and the like. So I was wondering if there was an easy way to create and bind to "settings/configuration" values to XAML?

Right now I just create a setting in the project, shove a bindable property into the XAML's DataContext and go from there. But my settings count is getting pretty crazy and managing them is getting painful (boring, repetitive, and annoying).

In an ideal world I'd like a system where I can do something like this:

```
<Window State={Binding {Settings Name="MyWindowState", DefaultValue="Normal"}}/>
```

If the "MyWindowState" setting doesn't exist, it would be created automatically and stored somewhere. And if the MyWindowState setting changes, all the bindings that use it would also be notified and updated accordingly. And the DefaultValue would be used if the setting retrieval failed.

Does something akin to this exist already, or can it be achieved with the standard WPF XAML?

I am planning on working on something that can do this, but if a proven solution already exists I would love to at least look at it/hear it out.

From what I understand [Telerik's persistance framework](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/persistenceframework.aspx) can do something like this, except on a  control to control basis (there is no global "settings" I can bind to), at least on first glance.

Comment: you might find this useful: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2008/11/18/wpf-binding-to-application-settings-using-a-markup-extension/

Comment: @PeterRitchie That is 1/3 of the way there, but I'd like to avoid having to manually go and create a setting in the project itself (that way I can reuse my controls in other projects without worrying about missing settings), while at the same time update all bindings that hit the configuration property if it changes.

Comment: From what I understood you have a settings file that stores same information that your window xaml file does. In xaml you can also set width, positions, content..etc so the question is why you duplicating xaml? Why dont you change the build action of your xaml to content and load xaml file at runtime on startup or save the current window elements state back to xaml on application shutdown event?? xaml is nothing else than xml just with custom parses allowing custom tags

Comment: @devhedgehog I am not storing anything in the XAML file, currently I am using the .NET built in project settings to store the data. Which works, but like I said it's getting pretty annoying dealing with quite a large number of settings.

Comment: What do you mean you do not store anything in xaml file? Of course you do your window and all elements are in xaml file already else you wouldnt be in wpf :) I said just instead of letting .net compile your xaml in baml you take the option to keep it raw xaml and load it at runtime that would allow you to manipulate your xaml files :) This approach would lead to let your settings file away its all in xaml anyways :)

Comment: @devhedgehog Sorry I meant I wasn't storing the specific settings in the XAML file, I just would like access to some sort of "setting's storage" mechanism, that would qualify the binding at runtime and allow many different xaml controls to bind to the same "setting".

Comment: Ok then you seem to be asking for globalization. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718(v=vs.110).aspx you could use your settings with x:static in wpf

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of database or observable dictionary that acts in place of the settings (wrapping them in effect) and can then be referenced instead of the settings. Hmmm....

Comment: I think, we can store the customized settings in configuration (for example App.config) file and retrieval process in code behind and bind with Binding concept using StaticResource/DynamicResource. Default value would be in code behind (as initial value for the property) instead XAML (no alternate way I able to find so far).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite possible. If you have an application properties file, you can access it like this:

```
Height="{Binding MainWindowHeight, Mode=TwoWay, Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}}"
```

where `MainWindowHeight` is a setting (in my case, an int). You'll also need to include this in the top of your XAML file, in the `Window` or `UserControl` tag:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:APPLICATION_NAME.Properties"
```

where APPLICATION_NAME is the name of your application.

EDIT: The binding can be have any mode, I just use TwoWay so I don't have to have any actual code to update it. For the positioning of my windows, it works out nicely that way.

EDIT: Also, this can't dynamically create settings. I would use an XML file in your application, make a class to handle that, and then bind to a method of the class to get/dynamically create the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an attached property:

```
<Window loc:WindowState.Name="MyWindowState" />
```

In the [OnNameChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler of your attached property you will have access to the `Window` instance that the WindowState.Name property was set on and access to the value (*"MyWindowState"* in this example) that was set. There you start listening (e.g. using [PropertyChangedEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to changes of all properties of your `Window` instance that are part of your window state that you want to persist.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use WPF's theming option. You can store settings of your controls (width, color...) in a theme file, which is nothing but an xml file. You may store this xml somewhere and load it at runtime. You can update this xml when the application exits with the changes. And load it when the application opens next.